# How to set maxmemory for RedisCloud addon on heroku ( rails app )?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, redis, redis-rails

If memory consumption goes over available memory app crashes.

So far I've changed memory-policy from `volatile-lru` to `allkeys-lru` via plugin's dashboard. However I'm not sure it'll work since I'm not sure of maxmemory it'll try to use.

redis-rails doesn't give a config option for maxmemory (it seems) and I believe I don't have access to redis.conf file. (or do I?)

So what are my options?

Answer (score 0):

The `maxmemory` is automatically set by the plan that you choose, i.e. the free tier sets it to 30mb.

> I believe I don't have access to redis.conf file.

That is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it in Redis Cloud's UI. As of now (Oct 2022), you go to Databases > choose your instance > Durability section, and you will find a drop down menu for "Data eviction policy".